# Gratis GUI client for DynamoDB

Tags: windows, gratis, amazon, database-browser

I am looking for a client for [Amazon DynamoDB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_DynamoDB) with the following features:

- GUI
- gratis
- works on Windows
- can write and execute queries
- can save queries' results

E.g. with MySQL I use [MySQL Workbench](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL_Workbench), with PostgreSQL I use [pgadmin](http://www.pgadmin.org/), with Oracle Database I use [Oracle SQL Developer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_SQL_Developer), etc. I am basically looking for a [database administration tool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Database_administration_tools) that supports Amazon DynamoDB and that is gratis (unlike [RazorSQL's Amazon DynamoDB SQL Editor](http://razorsql.com/features/dynamodb_sql_editor.html)).

---

RazorSQL's Amazon DynamoDB SQL Editor (non-gratis):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [AWS Toolkit for Eclipse](http://aws.amazon.com/eclipse/) or [AWS Toolkit for Visual Studio](http://aws.amazon.com/visualstudio/). Both are gratis (assuming that you have Visual Studio for the latter), work on Windows, are GUI, can write and execute queries, and can save queries' results.

AWS Toolkit for Eclipse:

[image]

AWS Toolkit for Visual Studio :

[image]

Comment: How do you write sql queries in the AWS Toolkit for Visual Studio.?
I do not think this is possible. You can only make a select and paginate the result.

Comment: You might also use https://dynobase.dev

Comment: @RafalWiliński thanks, looks nice, you're welcome to convert your comment into an answer!

Answer (score 1):

You might also use [Dynobase](https://dynobase.dev).

- It works on Mac, Windows and Linux
- [non-gratis](https://dynobase.dev/#pricing)
- [feature list](https://dynobase.dev/#features)

[image]

Disclaimer: I am the founder of Dynobase.dev.